# LinkedQueue using a container of objects in Python does not work as expected

Tags: python, object, python-2.7, data-structures, queue

I am trying to implement a linked Queue using a container of Nodes(objects). My code is below. As you can see the output, the second value is being skipped  when dequeuing for some reason. Probably, there is a defect somewhere. I am finding it hard to grasp, as to exactly what is happening with the objects. Please help!

**Code:**

```
# Queue FIFO as a container of Nodes(objects)
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class LinkedQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.front = None
        self.back = None

    def dequeue(self):
        #print self.front.__dict__, self.front.next
        if self.front:
            value = self.front.value
            self.front = self.front.next
            return value
        raise Exception('Queue Empty! Cannot dequeue')

    def enqueue(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        if self.front:
            self.front.next = node
        else:
            self.front = node
        self.back = node  
        if not self.front is None:
            print 'BACK: ', self.back.__dict__, self.back.next
            print 'FRONT: ', self.front.__dict__, self.front.next
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = LinkedQueue()
    queue.enqueue(11)
    queue.enqueue(10)
    queue.enqueue(9)
    print
    print
    print queue.dequeue()
    print queue.dequeue()
```

**Output:**

```
BACK:  {'value': 11, 'next': None} None
FRONT:  {'value': 11, 'next': None} None
BACK:  {'value': 10, 'next': None} None
FRONT:  {'value': 11, 'next': <__main__.Node object at 0x1048cdb10>} <__main__.Node object at 0x1048cdb10>
BACK:  {'value': 9, 'next': None} None
FRONT:  {'value': 11, 'next': <__main__.Node object at 0x1048cdb50>} <__main__.Node object at 0x1048cdb50>


11
9
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `enqueue` function, this segment of code looks suspicious.

```
 if self.front:
        self.front.next = node
```

Every time the `enqueue` function is called, the above portion of the code will overwrite the second node.
(`self.front` doesn't appear to be changing anywhere)

Answer (score 1):

As harry wrote, there is a problem with your enqueue function.

```
if self.front:
    self.front.next = node
```

There should be BACK reference, like:

```
if self.front:
    self.back.next = node
```

Because you need to append it to the end of the queue. Now it should work.